# Can a female aspirant perform Siddhasana?

Tags: women, hatha-yoga, siddhasana

[Hatha yoga pradipika](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hatha_Yoga_Pradipika) contains posture details of Siddhasana as follows

> Press firmly the heel of the left foot against the perineum, and the
> right heel above the **male** organ. With the chin pressing on the chest,
> one should sit calmly, having restrained the senses, and gaze steadily
> the space between the eyebrows. This is called the Siddha Âsana, the
> opener of the door of salvation.
>
> [[37, Chapter 1, THE HAṬHA YOGA PRADIPIKA]](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/hyp/hyp03.htm)

It indicates the maleness in performing Siddhasana.

Can females perform siddhasana as per scriptures?

Comment: hatha yoga is a form of exercises, it is not an integral part of the hindu religion.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda It is an exercise for salvation.

Comment: @hanugm Same posture can be used by female aspirants. That is female organ instead of male's.

Comment: The actual Sanskrit also has the word often translated as clitoris. Yoni is also used in the  Māṇḍūkya Upaniṣad in a context where that doesn't make the least bit of sense. My guess is the words for "male organ" and "female organ" are actually invisibly present in both men and women, they are just more pronounced in some than others.

Comment: Per the Bihar School of Yoga's _Meditation from the Tantras_ the equivalent pose for women is the _Siddha Yoni Asana_. It differs from _Siddhasana_ only in the matter of where the left heel is placed, details [here](https://www.google.com/books/edition/_/_bpWAAAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=labia)

Comment: @iruvar I would encourage you to post an answer since you already have valid sources to be backed up. :)

Answer (score 3):

The question basically boils down to whether it is allowed for a female aspirant to perform the Yogic postures or not. And, the answer is yes, but I don't have any direct reference.

Yogi is the term used to denote a male aspirant who is adept in the practice of Yoga. For the women the corresponding term exists in scripture and it is Yogini.

Hatha Yoga Pradipika (in the 3rd chapter) itself uses the term Yogini on more than one occasion.

> Rakshedākuñchanādūrdhvam yā rajah sā hi yoghinī
>  Atītānāghatam
> vetti khecharī cha bhaveddhruvam |
>
> She who preserves by upward contraction her rajas is a Yogini. She
> knows the past and the future and certainly attains perfection in
> Khechari.

So, it is here implicitly implied that a female aspirant can also perform all the practice mentioned in the text and hence she can also practice Siddhasana which is one of the many Yogic postures defined in the text. As for the mention of the male organ in the verse, IMO it should be understood as an indication of the place where the heel is to be placed and not as indicative of something else.