# Which substance in a female body is converted to Ojas?

Tags: yoga, women, spirituality, brahmacharya

For males, it's told that it's the semen ( *vírya* ), that when preserved via *Brahmacharya* gets converted to [Ojas](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/18866/17833), travelling upto *ajña chakra*, by the process called *[Urdhareta](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/29653/17833)*.

So, as per the relevant scriptures, what is the equivalent (for the semen), that is transformed to *Ojas* in the case of females?  And what are some ways or methods (like *ãsanas*, lifestyle practices, etc.), specifically for women, to achieve that?  Is *Rajas*, called the female equivalent of the *Ojas (as in males)*?

Comment: For women it’s called Rajas. Have a look at the answer here: [Can a female aspirant perform Siddhasana?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/43367/can-a-female-aspirant-perform-siddhasana?r=SearchResults)

Comment: @Archit, thanks, it was somewhat a **bit** helpful.